# sccept attribut for file upload not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

```
   <input type="file" name="userImage" id="userImage"
 accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg">
```

This is working in Chrome.But not working in Firefox.

Not working means it is allowing user to upload word and excel documents also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/number-state.html#file-upload-state) don't impose any restrictions on the user agent. The main purpose of the `accept` attribute is to provide a UI that's best suited for the listed file types.

Chrome restricts the file selection to those types, but let's you always switch to "All files". Firefox seems to do it the other way round.

None of the browsers prevents a user to submit a file with a type not listed in the `accept` attribute.